# Arithmetic mean of geometric means

Tags: means

I am looking for a simple closed-form expression simplifying the sum (or average, if you prefer) of the geometric means of all subsamples $A\subset X$ of cardinality $|A|=k$ from a grand set $X$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{A\subset X: |A|=k}\left(\prod_{x\in A} x \right)^{1/|A|}
\end{equation*}
Is there any identity that would allow for such simplification?

The question is motivated by the expression
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{e\in\{0,1\}^N:\sum_i e_i=k}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i e_i \right)
\end{equation*}
which I am hoping to simplify.